# optimize mySql query performance using index

Tags: mysql

I am having below query. I am using mysql database

```
Explain  
SELECT
  a.ProductID,
  a.ProductName,
  b.ShelfID,
  b.SCode,
  c.CompanyID,
  c.CompanyName,
  d.CategoryName,
  ProdCategoryID
FROM tblProduct a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblShelfComp b
  ON a.ProductSID = b.ShelfID
INNER JOIN tblCompany c
  ON a.ProductCompId = c.CompId
LEFT OUTER JOIN tclCategory d
  ON a.CategoryID = d.CategoryID
ORDER BY a.ProductName
```

Gives o/p

```
id  Select_type table   type    Possible_keys   Key Key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  45850      Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  b   Eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 34  a. ProductSID   1   (NULL)
1   SIMPLE  c   Eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 34  a. ProductCompId    1   (NULL)
1   SIMPLE  d   Eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 34  a. CategoryID   1   (NULL)
```

This query takes a while to execute. So I am using explain to know how is it functioning. But I am not able to determine what to do with this result. What steps I need to take to optimize the performance?

Comment: How long does your query take for how many resulting rows?

Comment: It takes almost 20sec to execute. Returning 45k rows

Comment: The only thing that concerns me is the length of the primary key fields used for the joins. Suggests that they are not integer fields. Integers tend to be more efficient for joins.

Comment: Yup the primary keys are varchar.

Comment: If they are numerics stored in a VARCHAR field then try changing that in a test copy and see if the performance improves. If not numerics then you might need a fairly major redesign to gain anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does it take to run the query if you do not use "ORDER BY"? If this is about the same amount of time, there is no optimization potential for your query. (Maybe invest in better hardware/faster disk - or tweak your mysql server values for optimization?)

If it is considerably faster, you could try to create an index on tblProduct.ProductName. Not shure if this helps, though.